# Excel VBA Calculate last row for each worksheet storing the value with a different name

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I need to calculate the last row in every worksheet of my excel workbook and I'm actually doing that with the following lines of code:

```
With Sheets("Sheetname")
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
    LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
Else
    LastRow = 1
End If
End With
```

Is it possible to loop over every worksheet and store the LastRow values with a different name every time? I need all of them to be stored separately in my Macro.

Comment: Use a collection, dictionary or an array to store the information.  I would use a dictionary with sheet name as the key and the lastrow as the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through Worksheets like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'do something
Next ws
```

You could use a Scripting.Dictionary to store your values with `ws.Name` as Key and your `.Cells.Find` as Value. Place the code where the `'do something` comment is.

Comment: I don't need to evaluate if a worksheet is empty in my case and I wanted to avoid to use `.UsedRange` because sometimes it fails to calculate the actual last row in a sheet. Do I have to add the keys and the values to a dictionary within the for loops? As  you suggest it looks like better to do it after the loop.

Comment: @AleB Sorry, didn't read the question properly. You have to add the items inside the loop.

Comment: No problem, your answer helped me anyway. Unfortunately it turned out that a for loop is not suitable for what I should do in this case, because one of the worksheets is not filled at the beginning and one of the values in the dictionary results to be wrong. To solve such issue probably I need to avoid loops and calculate "LastRowValue" singularly.